# MongoDB update if value from one array is in other array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection (1) with the following field:

```
{
 _id: 1,
 value: ["A","B","C","D"]
}
```

and inside another collection (2), I have the following fields:

```
{
 _id: 1,
 predicted_value: [
  {
   value: "A",
   num: 1,
  },
  {
   value: "B",
   num: 2,
  },       
  {
   value: "D",
   num: 2
  }
 ],
 real_prediction: <Collection1.value>
 predicted_by: "Person1",
 is_correct_prediction: <bool>
}
```

My goal is now to update the second collection by the following: If an entry gets put into value of collection 1 (I already am listening to this type of event), collection 2 should update the real prediction by gathering the values of collection 1 and update the boolean is_correct_prediction, if one element in the value array is also in the predicted_value array. In this case it should be set to True, by default it is False. Is there some sort of mongo query, that can manage this? It can definetly be done with Python, but is it possible to also use mongo only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a `$lookup` to collection 1 and use `$setIntersection` to check whether `is_correct_prediction` should be true.

```js
db.coll2.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "coll1",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "coll1Lookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$coll1Lookup"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      real_prediction: "$coll1Lookup.value",
      is_correct_prediction: {
        $ne: [
          [],
          {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$coll1Lookup.value",
              "$predicted_value.value"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "coll1Lookup"
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "coll2",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NEhS2X6weYU)

Comment: I will definetly try this out! Thanks a lot! One last question, I found out that lookup only allows the same collection, is there an option to access a collection from another database?

Comment: @AGI_Max What do you mean by *lookup only allows the same collection*? `$lookup` is meant to perform data correlation between different collections.

Comment: I used the wrong term, my bad. I meant lookups on a different database.

Comment: @AGI_Max Currently MongoDB does not support cross-database lookup. You may want to check out [this feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34935) for the status update.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! The query helped a lot. I still needed to use a little bit of python, but with way less loops :)